# Could it be that the drupal database doesn't work anymore after using jquery .load()

Tags: ajax, database, javascript

After using jquery .load() in drupal 7, the database doesn't seem to work

***module***

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>            
   function loadPage (id,level) {
   $.ajax({   
          beforeSend: function () {   
            // here you can do things before the action start    
          },
          success: function () {
          $('#contenpage').load(\"$path/pages/page.php\", { 'var': [id,level]})
          }
        });
   } 
   </script>
```

I want to use the database in the page "page" and echo the result back.

***page***

```
 $query = db_select('course_function', 'f');
  $query
      ->fields('f', array('id'))
      ->condition('f.chapter_id', $id, '=')
  ;
  $result = $query->execute();
  print_r($result);
  foreach ($result as $res) {
    $id = $res->id;
  }
echo $id;
```

But it does not work - do I need to use the PHP manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely that drupal database API is not available in your page.php file because corresponding files are not included in it. What I usually do if I want to do stuff like this, is declaring a menu item:

```
function MYMODULE_menu(){
    $items['path/page'] = array(
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        'page callback' => 'your_function_name',
        'title' => 'AJAX: Page callback'
    );
    return $items;
}
```

the code above adds a new page to drupal menu system and makes it available as: http://www.yoursite.com/path/page

and then in your function

```
function your_function_name() {
    $query = db_select('course_function', 'f');
    $query->fields('f', array('id'))
          ->condition('f.chapter_id', $id, '=');
    $result = $query->execute();
    print_r($result);
    foreach ($result as $res) {
        $id = $res->id;
    }
    echo $id;
    //You need to have exit in such callback functions to prevent drupal theme 
    //functions from taking over the page processing
    exit;
}
```

Then in your javascript you can approach this page just like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>            
function loadPage (id,level) {
$.ajax({   
      beforeSend: function () {   
        // here you can do things before the action start    
      },
      success: function () {
          $('#contenpage').load("http://yoursite.com/pages/page", { 'var': [id,level]})
      }
    });
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you verry much,
if I had more points, I would give it +1